# WPF: Bind to class properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using `MVVM`, I am trying to bind three `TextBox`'s to a `Client` class properties as follow:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.NameInLatin, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" >
    <TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.IDNumber, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Margin="5" />
    <Button Content="{Binding ScanLabel,Source={StaticResource LocalStrings}}"  Margin="4"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In my View Model I defined the `NewClient` property the classic way:

```
private Client newClient;
public Client NewClient
{
     get { return newClient; }
     set
     {
         newClient = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("NewClient");
     }
}
```

When place a breakpoint inside a boolean property just to test the value of `newClient`, and I find it null.

So why is it the `newClient` property loses it's value?

---

Here is the entire `xaml` part:

```
<Border Background="AntiqueWhite"
        DataContext="{StaticResource ServicesViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameLabel, Source={StaticResource LocalStrings}}"
                    Style="{StaticResource SubTitles}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameInLatinLabel, Source={StaticResource LocalStrings}}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource SubTitles}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IDNumberLabel, Source={StaticResource LocalStrings}}"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Style="{StaticResource SubTitles}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.NameInLatin, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding NewClient.IDNumber, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            <Button Content="{Binding ScanLabel,Source={StaticResource LocalStrings}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I tired to bind to a property I created called `Name`, and the binding did work.

Comment: which Boolean property looses data ?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new Client in your private field. Do it in constructor instead. In Addition, you have to check in the setter, if value equals newClient then you return.

Comment: ^^ does that make any difference here ?

Comment: not the boolean property, the boolean property I used it for testing. NewClient class is the one that loses it's value.

Comment: @Guerudo, yes initially it was in the constructor, what's in the code is just something I tried, I'll edit right now

Comment: there can be a few scenarios - either your property is set again, of your field newClient is being revalued from some other place, or the object that you are referring to is a different object all together

Comment: But a binding won't use your setter of NewClient, because you bind to its fields not to the whole object. Did you set DataContext etc. properly? Maybe this binding doesn't work at all.

Comment: How do you know your binding works? You should set a breakpoint inside a field you are binding to, also you can check output if it shows some binding errors. Did you set DataContext, which is required to make bindings work? What's more you could try to check this {Binding NewClient.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by setting the DataContext properly?

Comment: @Ayoub.A read about attaching ViewModel to View You should set DataContext of your Window to ViewModel (or wherever your NewClient is).

Comment: @WojciechKulik I edited my question, it now shows how I bound the DataContext.

Comment: Did you try: {Binding NewClient.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}?

Comment: yes I tried it right now, it didn't work

Comment: So probably binding doesn't work, check out Output window. Try to set DataContext = new ServicesViewModel() from code behind (*.xaml.cs) instead of StaticResource, maybe there is a problem. I can't tell you more according to the code you provided. Make sure that NewClient is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

By default `TextBox.Text` updates when a control loses focus, so if you need to update your property every time text changes you should use binding like this:

```
{Binding NewClient.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

[How to: Control When the TextBox Text Updates the Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If it still doesn't work, then probably NewClient is not initalized. In Debug Output window should show you issues with bindings.

Comment: I have initialized NewClient, as I have added in my question I created a string property called Name and bound the TextBox to it and it worked fine. in other words when the problem is how to bind to perperties that exist in a class other than the view model

Comment: I guess you need to show your VM, at least the related part, because it has to work. Something is not right in VM then.

Comment: I also have initialized NewClient and set it's values in the constructor, and they did appear in the TextBox. ( this is of course after a changed the Mode to TwoWay). So the binding does happen from the source to the UI but it doesn't happen in the other way

Comment: Ok, I'll give you a solution: prepare a clean (new) project with one view and one viewmodel and one model Client - try to bind it, don't copy anything from your old project. It has to work (then you will be able to find a difference). If not, you will be able to show us a sample project and then it will be easy to fix it.

Comment: I have finally found where is the error. when I checked the values of the NewClient class, I did it inside a boolean field setter as mentioned in my question, and for some reason they were reset to null. However when I created a Button and checked for my NewClient properties values inside it's Command, they were as enterred in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the name of the item held in the datacontext. Simply report its property only:

Before:

```
Binding NewClient.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource
```

after

```
Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource
```

Also `OneWayToSource` is primarily used for *read-only* data. Remove that to

```
 Binding Name
```

Comment: If it's the case the there will be another problem. I have NewClient and OldClient, both of the are instances of the same class, which one of them will be edited? I tried it anyway, and non of them was both of them had null properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar problem. In ViewModel I did binding to a Class property.

```
class SampleClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

class ViewModelClass
{
    public SampleClass Sample {get; set;}
}
```

And I found thhat for binding to work, should be used Properties in SampleClass, not Fields. It helped me.